# testing js files using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I try to understand how to test js files.
Look, I have a file emotify.js with function:

```
function emotify(string) {
 return string + '' + ' :)'; 
}
```

and then I created another file - index.js with the content below:

```
var emotify = require('./emotify.js');
console.log(emotify('just testing'));
```

but console push me an error

```
 TypeError: emotify is not a function
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8

Answer (score 3):

When you require a module the result is what the module have exported. In this case you will need to export your function:

emotify.js code:

```
module.exports = function(string) {
 return string + '' + ' :)'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Variant 1

emotify.js:

```
module.exports = function emotify(string) { // Named function, good for call stack at debugging. You are pro, right ?
 return string + '' + ' :)'; 
}
```

test.js:

```
const emotify = require('./emotify.js'); // const instead of var, cause you are pro :)
console.log(emotify('just testing'));
```

## Variant 2

mylib.js:

```
function emotify(string) {
 return string + '' + ' :)'; 
}

function anotherFunc(string) {
 return string + '' + ' :)'; 
}

module.exports = {
 emotify,
 anotherFunc,
};
```

test.js:

```
const mylib = require('./mylib.js');

console.log(mylib.emotify('just testing'));
console.log(mylib.anotherFunc('just testing'));
```

================

Useful links:

- https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html
- https://jestjs.io/